# How do I clear the shape information of tf.Tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

Suppose during training a network, we resize all images to 512*512, so there might be a `tf.Tensor` named `input:0`, which is of shape `(batch_size, 512, 512, 3)`.

However, when making predictions, it is possible to feed images of multiple sizes into the network. So the shape of tensor `input:0` should be something like `(batch_size, None, None, 3)`, since the size of images are unknown.

So if I have a Tensor of shape `(batch_size, 512, 512, 3)`, how do I "reshape" it to `(batch_size, None, None, 3)`? I tried

```py
inputs=tf.reshape(inputs, (batch_size, tf.shape(inputs)[1], tf.shape(inputs)[2], 3)
```

but the output is still of shape `(batch_size, 512, 512, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can resize/rescale the weight/bias terms in a neural network. But it would be pretty easy to resize your image input to 512*512. Have you considered that?